# Android custom button sensitivity

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android

I have created a custom button like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false">        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/title_dark_red" 
                android:startColor="@color/title_red"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/red_stroke" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true">        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/title_pressed_red" 
                android:startColor="@color/title_pressed_red"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/red_stroke" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>   
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true">        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/title_pressed_red" 
                android:startColor="@color/title_pressed_red"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/red_stroke" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The problem is sensitivity of the button is very bad, not like the regular buttons. The buttons are not too small in the screen, so it's easy to touch.

What can be the problem ?

P.S I'm using Button.OnClickListener() to set click handler.

Button is in relative layout structure :

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
```

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titlePlace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/expand_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/showButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/showButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Places"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a hardware related question. Software just takes on click event sent by hardware and checks whether it's in view's bounds.

Other potential issues:

- inaccurate touch screen
- view was animated and moved to different position
- view is too small or finger too big ;)

Comment: It's not about the hardware i think. I tried on different device.

Comment: Try to click with mouse in emulator.